# Using all scss features in a project necessary?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

Is it really necessary ? like loops , list etc ... Is using those feature really necessary in a project ?

Yes,Mixins,Variables,Extend,Nesting,PartialImport are necessary . But are other functions , loops ,list really used on daily basis on projects?

__I AM A BEGINEER (Noobie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As projects has different requirements differs the used tools which are used to build a project. So, the answer to your question is no. The different features are not allways needed alltogether in all project. But all the named features are basic and common used features to that language.

And as you don't know what features are needed for the next project: if you want to code in SASS (or become a good coder) you should know all the features and have basic knowledge about how they work and how to use them. But as you are a beginner: that comes with time when you have to use the different features with every project you realise.